# How to exclude folders in a react vite typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I have a project with Vite, React and Typescript.

I am trying to exclude specific folder from the build so that the files won't be added to production by accident.

I added the excluded folder to **tsconfig.json** in the following way:

```
{
   extends: ...
   compilerOptions: {...}
   ...
   include: ["src/**/*"],
   exclude: ["src/excluded-folder/**/*.*"]
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "<some file included in build>" from "<a file that was excluded>".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to a library named [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external).

You need to add the excluded files to the Rollup configuration in addition to the typescript exclusion.

In your **vite.config.js** file, mark the files as external:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import glob from 'glob';
...
const excludedFiles = (process.env.VITE_ENVIRONMENT === "PROD" ? [
    "./src/excluded-folder/**/*.*",

] : []).map(pattern => glob.sync(pattern)).reduce((acc, current) =>
    [...acc, ...current], []
).map((path) => fileURLToPath(new URL(path, import.meta.url)));


export default defineConfig({
    ...
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: excludedFiles
        }
    }
```